# Add content form database to Pells WYSIWYG text editor (Edit function)

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Im using Pell's WYSIWYG text editor on my site.
https://github.com/jaredreich/pell

Its working fine to create content and save that on the databse, but id like also to edit by import the text from databse into the editor like i do on input with value="$var".

I tried following withouth success:

```
<div id="editor" value="$VAR" class="pell">$VAR</div>
<div>
  HTML output:
  <textarea class="displayno" value="$VAR" id="html-output"  name="catdesc[]">$VAR</textarea>
</div>
```

May it will be necessary to import the text inside the init of this script:

```
var editor = window.pell.init({
element: document.getElementById(\'editor\'),
defaultParagraphSeparator: \'p\',
onChange: function (html) {
    document.getElementById(\'html-output\').value = html
}
})
```

Can anyone help me out there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to do it bymyself:**

Add to init:

```
contentDatabase: function () {
    html = document.getElementById(\'html-outpu\').value;
    return html;
},
```

Inside the editor script add after intializing "content" and "settings":

```
  var addContentDatabse = settings.contentDatabase();
  if(addContentDatabse){
    content.innerHTML = addContentDatabse;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the editor object to add innerHTML like this:

```
var editor = window.pell.init({
element: document.getElementById(\'editor\'),
defaultParagraphSeparator: \'p\',
onChange: function (html) {
   document.getElementById(\'html-output\').value = html;
 }
})

editor.content.innerHTML = '<b>BOLD CONTENT</b>';
```